# Adding a page to a slider (html)

Tags: html, css, slider

I am dealing right now with making a home website using sliders. I tried to go from a [tutorial](https://designmodo.com/create-full-screen-slider/), and I want to add another slide. I think I modified the code accordingly, but it won't work. What do I miss?

Here is the link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jogcxhre/).

Here part of my css:

```
.slide-1 {
  background: #fbad99;
  left: 0;
}
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-5 {
  background: #b1a494;
  left: 400%;
}
.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.slider-content {
  width: 635px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page1,
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page5 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #ea2e49;
  background: transparent;
}

.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-400%);
  transform: translateX(-400%);
}

.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide-1 h2,
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slide-5 h2,
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide-1 h4,
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slide-5 h4,
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide-1 > img,
[ ... slide 2-4 ... ]
.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slide-5 > img {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are including slide 5 outside of `<div class="css-slider-wrapper">`. Move that last closing `</div>` tag from the bottom of slide 4 to the end of slide 5 and everything will be contained in slider wrapper. I just tried it in your fiddle and it worked